# How to write if_else condition within a function in r and then apply on all variables of a dataframe?

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I am writing a `function` to find `frequency` of all elements/levels of a variable if it's `character` and skip it if it's `numeric` but getting an error in the condition.

```
dummy_df <- data.frame(gender_vector = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"),
                          color_vector = c('blue', 'red', 'green', 'white', 'black'),
                       num_vector = c(1,2,3,4,5)
) 

dummy_df

  gender_vector color_vector num_vector
1          Male         blue          1
2        Female          red          2
3        Female        green          3
4          Male        white          4
5          Male        black          5
```

**code:**

Tried:

```
count_char_cols_fn2 <- function(df,selected_var){
  df %>% 
    if_else(class(.data[[selected_var]]) == "character",
            count(.data[[selected_var]]),
    )
}

purrr::map(df = dummy_df, 
           .x = names(dummy_df),
```

and

```
count_char_cols_fn2 <- function(df,selected_var){
  df %>% 
    if_else(class(df$selected_var) == "character",
            count(.data[[selected_var]]),
    )
}

purrr::map(df = dummy_df, 
           .x = names(dummy_df),
           .f = count_char_cols_fn2)
```

**Error in both code attempts:**

Error: `condition` must be a logical vector, not a `data.frame` object.

where as this works:

```
class(dummy_df$gender_vector)

[1] "character"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are checking class of one column at a time use `if` instead of `if_else`. Also you can use `is.character` to check if class is of type character.

```
library(dplyr)
   
count_char_cols_fn2 <- function(df,selected_var){
    if(is.character(df[[selected_var]]))  
      count(df, .data[[selected_var]])
}

purrr::map(names(dummy_df),count_char_cols_fn2, df = dummy_df)

#[[1]]
#  gender_vector n
#1        Female 2
#2          Male 3

#[[2]]
#  color_vector n
#1        black 1
#2         blue 1
#3        green 1
#4          red 1
#5        white 1

#[[3]]
#NULL
```

Comment: thanks again @Ronak. I was still thinking about the previous old problem of `select_if(is.character)` from earlier today and was trying by this `conditional` way. Thanks again for helping, really appreciate !!

Answer (score 2):

We could do this in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dummy_df %>% 
   summarise(across(where(is.character),  ~ list(table(.))))
```

Comment: thanks @akrun for showing another great way of writing code for this. Really appreciate!!